# Find previous X amount of siblings from certain point in list (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which sets the height of each article in a row.

```
                            if(window.innerWidth > 1024) {
                                var articleCount = 0;
                                $('.news-box li .article-content-wrap').each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) 
                                    { 
                                        maxHeight = $(this).height(); 
                                    }
                                    articleCount++;
                                    if(articleCount % COLUMNS_COUNT_LARGE == 0) {
                                        $(this).closest('.box-grid').prev().find('.article-content-wrap').height(maxHeight);
                                        $(this).closest('.box-grid').prev().prev().find('.article-content-wrap').height(maxHeight);
                                        $(this).height(maxHeight);
                                        maxHeight = 0;
                                    }
                                });
```

For example, the articles in the first row are 300px tall, and then the second row is 400px tall.

The above code works well for 3 columns, but 'COLUMNS_COUNT_LARGE' gets replaced by a number and this number can be changed which would mean I would need to adjust the number of .prev() siblings I select.

What I would like to do is select the previous X amount of siblings. For example, if the column count is 5 and I load the 10th article I want 6,7,8,9,10 to all have the same height.

I would have thought that .prev(5) would work for me, but I don't think this works.

I fear I am not making much sense here, but if someone can help that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To cover this part: `.prev()` uses a *selector* and `5` is not a selector

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear how the code you've shown relates to the issue, however you can use `nextAll()` and `prevAll()` along with `slice()` to get the nearest N siblings to an element:

```
let $prev5 = $element.prevAll().slice(5); 
let $next5 = $element.nextAll().slice(5);
```